# how to get first value of inner join distinct value from other table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

i have below picture and query. the problem is my query show me wrong value, in multiple records in does not show hotelname correct, means i want first hotel from VoucherHotelTable  but its show me Scond hotel due to Distinct i think please help me this how to handle

```
Select distinct v.VoucherId,u.Name,v.ArrivalFromCity,
       CAST(v.ArrivalDate  AS DATE) as ADDate, v.ArrivalFlightNo, hm.HotelName
from  VoucherMaster v
inner join UserMaster u on  v.AgentId = u.UserId
inner join VoucharHotel vh on v.VoucherId = vh.VoucharId
inner join HotelMaster hm on vh.HotelId = hm.HotelId
inner join AirportTerminal t on  v.ArrivalTerminalId = t.AirprtTerminalId 
where v.ArrivalDate  between '11/15/2018 12:00:00 AM'
    and '11/16/2018 12:00:00 AM'  AND v.ArrivalSectorId = 3
```

[image: Check Picture]

Comment: I don't see anything that would match your condition for `v.ArrivalDate  between '11/15/2018 12:00:00 AM' and '11/16/2018 12:00:00 AM' `. [Read this blog on how to improve your question](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977) with emphasis on [This sub post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok i wam editing my picture

Comment: If you have many corresponding entries in `VoucharHotel` table, you need a ranking function to get the first.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @scsimon   In AD date there is 11/15/2018 i show wrong date

Comment: DanB .. i am new in SQL server... :(  can you help me this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is working through partition by.
Try this. rank() function should return a rank for hotel for each voucher.

```
;with VoucherHotelRnk as (
    select voucherId, hotelId, date, rank() over(partition by voucherId order by date) rnk
    from VoucharHotel
)
Select v.VoucherId,u.Name,v.ArrivalFromCity,
       CAST(v.ArrivalDate  AS DATE) as ADDate, v.ArrivalFlightNo, hm.HotelName
from  VoucherMaster v
inner join UserMaster u on  v.AgentId = u.UserId
inner join VoucherHotelRnk vh on v.VoucherId = vh.VoucherId and vh.rnk = 1
inner join HotelMaster hm on vh.HotelId = hm.HotelId
inner join AirportTerminal t on  v.ArrivalTerminalId = t.AirprtTerminalId 
where v.ArrivalDate  between '11/15/2018 12:00:00 AM'
    and '11/16/2018 12:00:00 AM'  AND v.ArrivalSectorId = 3
```

Comment: Invalid column name 'voucherId'.  Invalid column name 'hotelId'.  Thanks for your answer highly appreciated  but its show me this error when i execute this query

Comment: I have updated my query.  I have forgot to mention voucherhotel table within the cte.

Comment: same erro  :( Invalid column name 'voucherId'.

Comment: It's not clear.  Your capture show voucharHotel (with a a), and a column voucherId (with a e).  And your query show voucharId (with a a).  I think you can fix mispelling error by yourself (not sure with is the good spelling in your DB).

Comment: Ok Thanks bro i will check

Comment: can you check this how to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53403330/how-to-get-data-from-sql-server-tocityid-and-fromcityid-bases/53406127#53406127

Answer (score -1):

```
;with VoucherHotelRnk as (
    select voucherId, hotelId, date, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by voucherId order by date) rowcount
    from VoucharHotel
)
Select v.VoucherId,u.Name,v.ArrivalFromCity,
       CAST(v.ArrivalDate  AS DATE) as ADDate, v.ArrivalFlightNo, hm.HotelName
from  VoucherMaster v
inner join UserMaster u on  v.AgentId = u.UserId
inner join VoucherHotelRnk vh on v.VoucherId = vh.VoucherId and vh.rowcount= 1
inner join HotelMaster hm on vh.HotelId = hm.HotelId
inner join AirportTerminal t on  v.ArrivalTerminalId = t.AirprtTerminalId 
where v.ArrivalDate  between '11/15/2018 12:00:00 AM'
    and '11/16/2018 12:00:00 AM'  AND v.ArrivalSectorId = 3
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for this to be an appropriate answer, you must first explain your answer, so that OP can understand WHY this is the correct solution, or determine whether it is NOT the correct solution. You cannot just post a code block.