# how to get data from SQL server ToCityId And FromCityId Bases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have below query I want to show data `fromCityId`  AND `ToCityId` .  Suppose passenger travel `fromCity` London `toCity` Manchester.  How do I write query like this,  when I use `where` clause and `in`, its show me same values in `fromcity` and `tocity`

Expected results are in below Picture

```
  Select vh.VoucharId,fCity.CityName as FromCity, tCity.CityName as ToCity, InDate 
    from VoucharHotel vh  
    inner join City fCity on   vh.City = fCity.CityId  inner join City tCity on
     vh.City = tCity.CityId 
     where vh.InDate  between '11/15/2018 12:00:00 AM' and '11/16/2018 12:00:00 AM'   AND City in (1,2)
```

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE VoucharHotel (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    VoucharId Int ,
    CityId int,
    HotelId  int,
    InDate Datetime,
    OutDate Datetime
);

CREATE TABLE City (
    CityId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    CityName varchar(200),
);
insert into City Values('London')
insert into City Values('Manchester')
insert into City Values('Birmingham')
insert into City Values('Leeds')

CREATE TABLE HotelMaster (
    HotelId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    HotelName varchar(200),
);
insert into HotelMaster Values('London Hotel')
insert into HotelMaster Values('Manchester Hotel')
insert into HotelMaster Values('Birmingham Hotel')
insert into HotelMaster Values('Leeds Hotel')

Insert into VoucharHotel Values(22,1,1,'11/15/2018', '11/16/2018')
Insert into VoucharHotel Values(22,2,2,'11/16/2018', '11/18/2018')
Insert into VoucharHotel Values(22,1,1,'11/18/2018', '11/20/2018')

Insert into VoucharHotel Values(23,2,2,'11/16/2018', '11/17/2018')
Insert into VoucharHotel Values(23,4,4,'11/17/2018', '11/20/2018')
Insert into VoucharHotel Values(23,2,2,'11/20/2018', '11/26/2018')
```

Answer (score 0):

Would the below resolve your problem:

```
with cte
(VoucherID,FromCity,ToCity,InDate)
as
(
select
    vh.VoucharId
,   fCity.CityName as FromCity
,   tCity.CityName as ToCity
,   InDate
from        VoucharHotel    vh
inner join  City            fCity on    vh.City = fCity.CityId
inner join  City            tCity on    vh.City = tCity.CityId 
where       vh.InDate  between '11/15/2018 12:00:00 AM' and '11/16/2018 12:00:00 AM'
)

select
*
from    cte
where   City in (1,2)
```

Let me know if you need changes made.

Comment: invalid City    in where clause

Comment: and when i run query without where clausse it show me wrong result

Comment: Could you provide me with some sample data, I will then be able to alter the answer to fit your needs.

Comment: OK wait 4 minutes

Comment: Thanks, I think I found the problem. Your joining the Cities with their ID's causing them to be the same. To resolve this, I suggest you add a passenger ID column in each of the tables, then you join them together, which will give you the expected results.

I can also do it for you, unless you want to quickly alter the sample data, then I'll provide you with the script...